# How can I observe multiple key paths with ractive?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, ractivejs

I'd like to observe changes to a key path per [docs on ractive observe](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-observe). However, I'd like to be able to observe multiple paths at the same time, eg, given:

```
var binding = new Ractive({
  el: '.here',
  data: {
    items: [
      {
        finished: false
      },
      {
        finished: false
      }  
    ]
  },
  template: someTemplate
})
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
binding.observe('items.*.finished')
```

Or similar to be able to watch the `finished` property of any item in the array.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as you described! http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/c3yc848z/

Note that the values of any `*` placeholders are passed to the callback as additional arguments, beyond the `(newValue, oldValue, keypath)` that you normally get – so in this case there'd be a fourth `index` argument.

Comment: lol it was right there in the docs `Any of the keys can be a * character, which is treated as a wildcard.`